# How do I add field values to the `drush user-create` command?

Tags: drupal, drush

I have been Googling this, read the drush documentation and searched StackOverflow, but I can't find an answer to this question.

I currently use `drush user-create someone@example.com --password="somepassword"` to create a user.

Then there are drush commands to add a role, block the user, etc. But nothing on adding/updating fields.

Does someone know how to set a custom user field to a created user, or immediately create a user with field values (for Drupal 7 that is)?
I need to do it without answering commandline questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a custom Drush command which accepts the arguments like UID and field values. 
https://www.chapterthree.com/blog/how-to-create-custom-drush-commands
https://drupalize.me/videos/passing-arguments-drush-commands?p=1134

All commands in user: (user)
 user-add-role (urol)  Add a role to the specified user accounts.
 user-block (ublk)     Block the specified user(s).
 user-cancel (ucan)    Cancel a user account with the specified name.
 user-create (ucrt)    Create a user account with the specified name.
 user-information      Print information about the specified user(s).
 (uinf)
 user-login (uli)      Display a one time login link for the given user account (defaults to uid 1). 
 user-password (upwd)  (Re)Set the password for the user account with the specified name.
 user-remove-role      Remove a role from the specified user accounts.
 (urrol)
 user-unblock (uublk)  Unblock the specified user(s).

Comment: That's pretty clever. I don't know why I didn't think of that, so thank you for your answer.